# Empirical Study of Auctions with Limited Data

Tags: reference-request, game-theory, empirical-evidence, auctions

I have limited real auction data which I am trying to see if I can do any empirical analysis. The data consists of auction type (i.e., forward or reverse), protocol (e.g., Vickrey, Dutch, English, etc.), winning bid value, 2nd highest bid, length of auction and number of bidders. The dataset is large (~500+ for each protocol). I do not have bid-level information (e.g., how the bids are distributed for each auction) which really limits what I can do with the data.

As you see, the problem is that I do not have bid-level data (e.g., how each bidders were bidding). I had two ideas originally:

1. Determine whether bidders are bidding according to the Bayesian
   Nash strategy but I don't think it is possible to establish a
   distribution of valuations since I do not have bid-level data.
2. An analysis of the Revenue Equivalence Theorem by examining the
   actual seller revenue for each protocol versus the expected revenue
   but not sure if this is possible.

Any suggestions or suggestions of past studies will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your question? Is this a reference request for past empirical papers on auctions?

Comment: Yes - if you can provide some references from past empirical papers on auctions that would be great.

Comment: Have you considered ch 32 of the Handbook of IO:  "An Empirical Perspective on Auctions"?